# ContextStartedEvent not broadcasted on Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm migrating application to Spring boot. My application listen on `ContextStartedEvent` but it looks that Spring boot does not emit such event. I can change my application and listen on `ApplicationReadyEvent`, but according to [spring boot doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners), "old" events are still emitted.

I would like to keep my code unchanged as much as possible.

Question: Is ContextStartedEvent supported by Spring Boot or not?

Demo:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class EventExample {

    @EventListener(classes = ContextStartedEvent.class)
    void start() { System.out.println("Listen ContextStartedEvent");} //not called

    @EventListener(classes = ApplicationReadyEvent.class) 
    void start2(){System.out.println("Listen ApplicationReadyEvent");} //called

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(EventExample.class, args);
    }
}
```

Output

> Listen ApplicationReadyEvent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ContextStartedEvent` is sent when `ApplicationContext.start()` is called. However `SpringApplication.run()` doesn't call `start()`, it only calls `refresh()`. If you want `ContextStartedEvent` to be sent then you'll need to start the context. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(EventExample.class, args).start();
}
```

Comment: But should I call `start()`? In my application I extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`. `SpringBootServletInitializer` does not call `start()`, just `run()`, so I don't know if calling `start()` is wise.

Comment: Calling `start` has the effect of starting any `Lifecycle` beans. Only you can know if that's wise or not for your application. It sounds like you must have been calling it before your migration to Spring Boot so it probably is wise to call it now as well.

Comment: How to call `start` in tests with @SpringBootTest ?

Comment: @PavelVarchenko It depends on when and why you want to call `start()`. One option would be to inject the application context using `@Autowired` and call `start()` (and `stop()`) as needed in your test methods.