# Best way to initialize beans in Spring context after application started?

Tags: java, spring

I need to initialize beans in the Spring context after my application has started; currently, I initialize beans in a class with annotation *@Configuration* like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   @Inject
   @Bean
   public BeanA init(param1, param2, etc...) {
       --- Code to construct bean A ---
   }

   @Inject
   @Bean
   public BeanB init(param1, param2, etc...) {
       --- Code to construct bean B ---
   }
}
```

But some beans I need to initialize after application startup so my approach is create a class listen to ***ApplicationReadyEvent*** event in Spring and put the code to initialize beans in that class.

```
@Configuration
class ApplicationStartingListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>{
    ---- Code to init bean here ----

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        --- If I put init bean code in here, is it correct? ----
    }
}
```

Is this the best way? Or there are some other better solutions?

Comment: Try with @PostConstruct

Comment: @DanielC. 

I got this error when I add PostConstruct annotation:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Lifecycle method annotation requires a no-arg method:

Comment: There are some links which helps you to achieve your desired results. I hope it would help. [link1](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2012/07/spring-and-events-and-listeners.html)  [link2](http://www.naturalprogrammer.com/run-code-spring-boot-application-startup/) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206676/contextstartedevent-not-broadcasted-on-spring-boot)

Comment: I just post one approach using '@PostConstruct'

Comment: Also you could use CommandLineRunner Interface to run some init methods before the app is started.  You can inject all the beans an values that you need to the CommandLinerRunner

Comment: Try SmartInitializingSingleton

Comment: Just be aware that spring may create more than one context and thus `@PostConstruct` can be called multiple times.

Comment: What about Lazy annotation guys?

Answer (score 107):

I will enumerate other approaches in order to init beans, I grouped the approach in Standard Approach and Spring Boot Approach.

*Standard Approach*

1. `@PostConstruct`: it is just an annotation that triggers a method after bean is create, it doesn't allow input parameters.
2. `@Bean(init-method="somInitMehotd")`: this approach is totally related to Spring bean lifecycle and it is called after bean creation, if you are using another method with `@PostConstruct` annotation, then the `@PostConstruct` will be called first.  This approach doesn't allow input parameters.
3. `ApplicationListener`: this interface allows to listen the standard events related to the Context Lifecycle, also it can listen customized events.  For example: create a class `MyAppListener` and implements `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` in this case the `MyAppListener` will implement an `onApplicationEvent` method that receives a `ContextRefreshedEvent`

*Spring Boot Approach*

4. The runners: There are two very useful interfaces `CommandLineRunner` and `ApplicationRunner` both of them will run after ApplicationContext is created both of them allows to inject beans as input parameters.
5. Spring boot listeners: Spring Application gives some additional events than the standards events that comes from the Application Context.  One of the event is `ApplicationReadyEvent` and it is fire when the application is ready to receive request.  In order to listen this events just implements the `ApplicationListener` using `ApplicationReadyEvent` as generic.

Here is the example:

MyBean class has different methods that will be called for each approach listed above, every method will call a print method and that method has a Thread.sleep in order to validate the order that every listener is called.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
public class MyBean {

    private String myVar="";

    public MyBean(){

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstructInit(){

        this.myVar="Post init called";
        print();

    }

    public void beanInit(){

        this.myVar="Bean init called";
        print();
    }

    public void contextInit(){

        this.myVar="Context init called";
        print();
    }

    public void runnerInit(){

        this.myVar="Runner init called";
        print();
    }

    public void bootListenerInit(){

        this.myVar="Boot init called";
        print();
    }



    public void print(){
        System.out.println(this.myVar);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `ContextRefreshListener` class that will listen the `ContextRefreshedEvent` and handle it.

```
public class ContextRefreshListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        contextRefreshedEvent.getApplicationContext().getBean(MyBean.class).contextInit();

    }
}
```

And it is the `BootListener` that will receive the `ApplicationReadyEvent` that comes from Spring Application.

```
public class MyBootListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {
        applicationReadyEvent.getApplicationContext().getBean(MyBean.class).bootListenerInit();
    }
}
```

And finally the Spring Boot Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StackoverflowBootApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowBootApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Bean(name = "myBean", initMethod = "beanInit")
    public MyBean getMyBean(){
        return new MyBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public ContextRefreshListener getContextRefreshedListener(){return new ContextRefreshListener();}


    @Bean
    public MyBootListener getBootListener(){return new MyBootListener();}

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner getRunner(ApplicationContext ctx){
        return (args) -> {
            ctx.getBean(MyBean.class).runnerInit();
        };
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Post init called
Bean init called
Context init called
Runner init called 
Boot init called
```

`Post init called` output comes from

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    this.initByPostconstruct="Post init called";
```

`Bean init called` comes from the `initMethod` value

```
@Bean(name = "myBean", initMethod = "beanInit")
public MyBean getMyBean(){
    return new MyBean();
}
}
```

`Context init called` comes from `ContextRefreshedEvent`

```
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
    contextRefreshedEvent.getApplicationContext().getBean(MyBean.class).contextInit();

}
```

`Runner init called` comes from `CommandLineRunner`

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner getRunner(ApplicationContext ctx){
    return (args) -> {
        ctx.getBean(MyBean.class).runnerInit();
    };
}
```

`Boot init called` comes from `ApplicationReadyEvent`

```
   public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {
        applicationReadyEvent.getApplicationContext().getBean(MyBean.class).bootListenerInit();
    }
```

All the listed scenarios were triggered by `Spring`, I didi'nt call any of the events directly, all of them were called by `Spring Framework`.