# How to Schedule a job in a spring java application on startup

Tags: java, spring

I wanted to schedule some jobs once my spring web application is started. 
I tried using `ApplicationListener` with `ContextStartedEvent`, but it never get fired.

I came to know that due to lazy initialization of beans it is not predicable to be fired soon after start up. So I tried using `ContextRefreshedEvent` and noticed that it is getting fired multiple times while getting started up and that causes the job to be scheduled multiple times. So I am not sure what is the best way to do this with the following conditions.

1. Scheduling should happen soon after application is initialized.
2. It should happen only once.

Comment: Just use `@Scheduled` and let Spring take care of it.

Comment: I was in fact doing that ,but having the issue that it is getting scheduled multiple times. I believe spring also schedules on every ContextRefresh As I understand all Singleton beans get reinitialized on refresh .If so I am not sure how the scheduler is going to work.Will that also get destroyed and reinitialized on refresh ?

Comment: No it doesn't... If it is scheduled multiple times your bean is getting loaded twice and you basically have multiple instances of your bean. So I suspect the error is actually on your side by loading configurations or components twice.

Comment: found this, sums up all the ways you can achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747933/best-way-to-initialize-beans-in-spring-context-after-application-started

Answer (score 0):

Try `ApplicationPreparedEvent`. 
Below are the detail of other events you can use.

1. An `ApplicationStartingEvent` is sent at the start of a run but
   before any processing, except for the registration of listeners and
   initializers.
2. An `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` is sent when the
       Environment to be used in the context is known but before the
       context is created.
3. An `ApplicationPreparedEvent` is sent just before the refresh is
       started but after bean definitions have been loaded.
4. An `ApplicationStartedEvent` is sent after the context has been
       refreshed but before any application and command-line runners have
       been called.
5. An `ApplicationReadyEvent` is sent after any application and
       command-line runners have been called. It indicates that the
       application is ready to service
6. An `ApplicationFailedEvent` is sent if there is an exception on
       startup.

More reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners

Comment: I am not using Spring framework 4.3 without spring boot.I believe the events you mentioned are specific to spring boot

Comment: May I know whch version do you use?

Comment: That's a typo in your previous comment. That's why I misunderstood it. Try to use ``event.getApplicationContext()`` to find out which context the event is for. Because ``ContextRefreshedEvent `` would fire every time the context init or refreshed.

Comment: I see my context is getting loaded twice and so that might be the problem.Created a separate question for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797306/spring-web-context-is-getting-loaded-twice thank you