# Spring web context is getting loaded twice

Tags: java, spring

I could see in my logs my web application is getting initialized twice as follows.

`04-12@12:10:38   INFO ContextLoader:305 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started`

I have the following web.xml configuration. Please advise anything wrong this this configuration.

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml 
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

> Update - I tried java configuration as well as follows and issue still exists.That make me wonder what I am doing wrong !

```
   XmlWebApplicationContext context = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocations("/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml","/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml" ,"/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml");

    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

    XmlWebApplicationContext webContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
    webContext.setConfigLocations("/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml" );

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container
      .addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webContext));

    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
```

Comment: Not a solution to your problem but XML conifguration is the legacy solution, it is better to configure your Spring application programatically.

Here is a how to: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-vs-java-config

P.S. If your context is initialized twice, maybe you do both a Java and an XML configuration and that is where your redundancy comes from (?)

Comment: I tried java configuration as well,but same issue :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Nevertheless, the main point was: it is the recommended and easier way to go for the Java configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the context-param with this:

```
  <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
```