# How can I set channel name dynamically passed by user instead of specifying in properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ibm-mq

My spring boot application is connecting to IBM MQ. I have specific mq properties in the application. My requirement is to set channel name dynamically in the controller which comes in Path variables

Comment: url/channelName="channel_name"/mqName="mqName"

Comment: how your spring boot application connect to MQ Broker? Is it via JMS or  MQI channel?

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to use Path variables. Alternatively

Command-line arguments from spring-boot:run

```
spring-boot:run -DchannelName=xxx
```

When you run with java -jar

```
java -DchannelName=xxx -jar yourjava.jar
```

You can get the arguments by

```
System.getProperty('channelName');
```

Comment: I need to connect to mq when I hit controller. Not at server startup

Comment: AFAIK you can't create bean on restapi if you want to do that you have a way to initialize bean just look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747933/best-way-to-initialize-beans-in-spring-context-after-application-started?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MQI client, consider with a `Builder`. Use it to configure `MQQueueManager` properties, such as hostname, port, channel name and etc. For example:-

```
public class MQClient implements AutoCloseable{

    private MQQueueManager mqm;
    private String qmgrName;

    public MQClient(Builder b) throws MQException {

        Hashtable<String, Object> CONNECTION_PROPERTIES = new Hashtable<>();

        CONNECTION_PROPERTIES.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, b.hostname);
        CONNECTION_PROPERTIES.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, b.port);
        CONNECTION_PROPERTIES.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, b.channel);
        //...other conn configurations

        this.qmgrName = b.qmgrName;

        //Instantiate MQQueueManager and start MQCONN
        mqm = new MQQueueManager(this.qmgrName, CONNECTION_PROPERTIES);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {

        if(qmgrName!=null)
           mqm.close();
    }

    public static class Builder  {

        private String qmgrName;
        private String hostname;
        private int port;
        private String channel;

        public Builder(String  queueManagerName) {
            this.qmgrName = queueManagerName;
        }

        public Builder hostname(String hostname){
            this.hostname = hostname;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder port(int port){

            this.port = port;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder channel(String name) {
            channel = name;
            return this;
        }

        public MQClient build() throws MQException {
            return  new MQClient(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Then at `@Controller` or `@Service` class, you could instantiate `MQClient` like below:-

```
@Service
public class SimpleService implements SuratService { 


    @Override
    public void send(String channel){

        //Internally MQQueueManager instantiated and open MQCONN to MQ Server/Qmgr
        try(MQClient client = new MQClient.Builder("QMGR1")
                            .channel(channel)
                            .hostname("localhost")
                            .port(1414)
                            .build()) {

            //perform MQPUT

        } catch (MQException ex) {
           //Connection to Queue Manager failed
           //Log connection failure here
        }
    }
}
```

** The `Hashtable` properties overwrite `MQEnvironment` channel configuration. Refer to `MQQueueManager` javadoc for more details and settings. You may add new setting field at the builder depends on your requirement.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQQueueManager.html?view=embed